# Powerbi groupby filter for not seeing the data if it contains a specifiek value

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

iam trying to create a measure with a filter.
i have fields TPLNR and TXT04. A TPLNR contains double/triple records  with different TXT04 values.

TPLNR 4OR-TTE-A-TY09159 have 3 different values in TXT04. iam trying to create a measure that if a TPLNR has the value DLFL i dont want to see the other 2 values also in my output. in this case i dont want to see the TPLNR 4OR-TTE-A-TY09159 in my visual and table drill through. is it possible to create such measure?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFPgC.png)

could someone help me with this?

Comment: Which kind of measure do you need? (a Sum of something? an Average? something different?) can you provide a sort of sample of what you are looking for? ... In the end you will need a Measure display some data, but you could calculate a field with a flag that tells you to include or exclude some values, this will allow you to bring the logic out of the measure itself. (if appropriate)

Comment: i only need a measure for not displaying the TPLNR value if there is a DLFL value in the field TXT04.

So only when the TPLNR value has CRTE value in the TXT04 field has to be displayed.

Comment: In order to do that you can use the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-report-add-filter) functionality in the report itself, you can set filters per visual, page, or all pages. If this "way" is viable you will still need to calculate a flag (true/false) to filter out the rows, you can use M or DAX to calculate it.

Comment: Hi Giovanni,thank you for your message. 
do you know how to use a calculation flag?
how is the formula for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so, I suggest you use the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-report-add-filter) functionality offered by PowerBI, in this way you won't need a measure just to filter your data.

In order to make filtering easier, I suggest you use a flag to specify what to include or exclude, you can calculate it in 3 ways.

1. in your source, so it's already ready to use in PowerBI
2. Using M (Power Query)

   - Reference the existing table (which makes a sort of copy of it)
   - filter it to include only the rows you want to include or exclude
   - join with the original table and create you "flag" by managing missing values (a sort of COALESCE)
   - specify that this "clone" table must not be loaded into the model
3. Using DAX calculated column
   The formula might look like the one below

```
MyFilterFlag =
CALCULATE (
    CONTAINSROW ( VALUES ( 'Table'[TXT04] ), "DLFL" ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[TPLNR] )
)
```

The formula checks for the available values in the column TXT04, by keeping as a filter only TPLNR, in practice it behaves as a group by

If you need more conditions just add them to the checked expression (&& = AND)

```
CALCULATE (
    CONTAINSROW ( VALUES ( 'Table'[TXT04] ), "DLFL" )
    && CONTAINSROW ( VALUES ( 'Table'[INACT] ), "X" )
    ,ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[TPLNR] )
)
```

Comment: Hi Giovanni, i want to add an extra criteria field in the calculation.

CALCULATE(
   IF( CONTAINSROW(
        VALUES(
            FunctionalLocation[TXT04]
        ), "DLFL"
    ), VALUES(FunctionalLocation[INACT]),"X"),
    ALLEXCEPT(
        FunctionalLocation,FunctionalLocation[TPLNR]
    )
)

but its not working. Could you please let me know what iam doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to do... is that a check for the value "X" in column "INACT" ? what do you expect as a result? (you might want to open a new question if the explanation is long)

Comment: Hi Giovanni, i want to add column INACT with value "X" in the calculation. if TXT04 has DLFL in the value and also a "X" in INACT then it has to be true else false

Comment: Here you go, pls mark the answer as useful if this helped